# How do I find non-null combination of ha and ho

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I'm trying to find any non-null combination of ha and ho, e.g hahahoho, ha, ho, hoha...

```
chat_words = sorted(set(w for w in nltk.corpus.nps_chat.words()))

[w for w in words.words() if re.search('^[haho]+$',w)]
```

The result I get is:

```
['a',
 'aa',
 'ah',
 'aha',
 'aho',
 'h',
 'ha',
 'hah',
 'hao',
 'ho',
 'o',
 'oh',
 'oho',
 'a']
```

Answer (score 1):

your pattern : `'^[haho]+$'` matches any combination of those four separate characters, `h,a,h,o` (3 since `h` is repeated). If you want to specifically match for `ha` and `ho` you have to use the `|` token.

```
[w for w in words.words() if re.search('^(?:ha|ho)+$',w)]
```

Comment: what if I want a combination of hahahoho , ha, ho, hoha... How can I combine them?

Comment: I dont qutie understand what you mean by that but if you put an example of what you mean in an edit, I'd be more than glad to accommodate. right now, this pattern will match all of `hahahoho`, `ha`, `ho`, `hoha`

Comment: When I run your code I get: '['ha', 'ho']' I'm looking to get this '[hahahoho, ha, ho, hoha...]'

Comment: @Sam - he just told you the regex will match any of those.

Comment: well are those words even in your list of words? because if they were, this pattern would match them. if you are doing a list comprehension, you can't expect items that aren't in the list to appear after the list comprehension.

Comment: How about finding non-negative even numbers of a's followed by an odd number of b's for example, aab, aaaabbb, aabbb....

Comment: that's a completely different question (that I would be glad to answer) but you should just ask a new question. Try to work it out yourself first though, and only post an answer if you really can't think of anything. hint, you may need to use `aa` and `bb` rather than just `a` and `b` alone if you want to specifically match for even/odd.